# Updating the value of arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a static data inside my arraylist in a controller package. These are my codes in the controller package.

```
       for(int i=0;i<studentPic.length;i++){
          //i want to update the value of zero
         mStudentModels.add(new StudentModel(studentPic[i],status[i],studentName[i],courseAndYear[i],0));
       }

       public List<StudentModel> getStudentModels (){
       return mStudentModels;
       }
```

Now i want to update a certain data if it meets a certain condition:

```
     private void stopCountdown() {
    if (mTask != null) {
        mTask.interrupt();
        List<StudentModel> studentModels = studentData.getStudentModels();
        studentData = new StudentData();
        for(int i=0;i<studentModels.size();i++){
            StudentModel studentModel = studentModels.get(i);
            if(studentModels.get(i).getStatus()=="PRESENT"){
                mFirebaseDatabase.child("attendance").child(formattedDate).child("present").push().setValue(studentModel);
            }else if(studentModels.get(i).getStatus()=="LATE"){
                mFirebaseDatabase.child("attendance").child(formattedDate).child("late").push().setValue(studentModel);
            }else{
                 //i want to update the value of  zero here
                int absences = studentModel.getNumOfAbsences();
                studentModel.setNumOfAbsences(absences+1);
                mFirebaseDatabase.child("attendance").child(formattedDate).child("absent").push().setValue(studentModel);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

The problem is if i call studentData.getStudentModels(); the value always remains zero. Whats the problem with that?

Here's my controller:
        public class StudentData {

```
private List<StudentModel> mStudentModels;

public void setmStudentModels(List<StudentModel> mStudentModels) {
    this.mStudentModels = mStudentModels;
}

public StudentData(){
    mStudentModels = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] studentPic = {R.drawable.boy1, R.drawable.boy2, R.drawable.girl1, R.drawable.girl2, R.drawable.girl3,
            R.drawable.girl4, R.drawable.girl5, R.drawable.boy3, R.drawable.girl6, R.drawable.girl7,
            R.drawable.boy4, R.drawable.girl8, R.drawable.girl9, R.drawable.girl10, R.drawable.boy5,
            R.drawable.girl1, R.drawable.girl12, R.drawable.girl13, R.drawable.boy6, R.drawable.girl14};

    String[] status = {"ABSENT","LATE","PRESENT","PRESENT","PRESENT","PRESENT","PRESENT","PRESENT","PRESENT","PRESENT","PRESENT","PRESENT",
            "PRESENT","PRESENT","PRESENT","ABSENT","PRESENT","PRESENT","PRESENT","PRESENT"};
    String[] studentName = {"Andy Lim", "Benjamin Adams", "Karen Healey", "Anne Pierre", "Corine Alvarez",
            "Emily Hedrick", "Courtney Quick", "Oscar Renteria", "Ellen Joy", "Jesse Ramer",
            "Jackson Beck", "Alicia Hofer", "Jenae Rupp", "Allison Beitler", "Martin Hofkamp",
            "Emma Ruth", "Kathryn Berg", "Michelle Salgado", "Lewis Caskey", "Elizabeth Core"};
    String[] courseAndYear = {"BSIT-3", "BSIT 2", "BSIT-3","BSCS-3" , "BSCS-2", "BSIT-3", "BSIT-2", "BSIT-3", "BSIT-2", "BSIT-3",
            "BSCS-3", "BSCS-2", "BSCS-3", "BSCS-2", "BSCS-3", "BSIT-3", "BSCS-2", "BSIT-2", "BSCS-3", "BSCS-2"};


    for(int i=0;i<studentPic.length;i++){
         mStudentModels.add(new StudentModel(studentPic[i],status[i],studentName[i],courseAndYear[i],0));
    }




}

public List<StudentModel> getStudentModels (){
    return mStudentModels;
}
```

}

My model looks like this:

```
public StudentModel(int studentPic, String status, String studentName, String courseAndYear, int numOfAbsences) {
    this.studentPic = studentPic;
    this.status = status;
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.courseAndYear = courseAndYear;
    this.numOfAbsences = numOfAbsences;
}
```

Comment: it sounds like a race condition. do you know for sure that the student models are added before stopCountdown() is called

Comment: after the startCountdown() the student models should be called

Answer (score 0):

Looks like below checks need to do:

- Whether studentPic is not empty.
- Whether mStudentModels is not empty (Mainly whether mStudentModels is getting added before the call of stopCountdown() method).

If it does not fix the issue, please provide more information on the code of Controller side.

Comment: The thing is, if i updated the numOfAbsences in the stopCountDown() it should also update the value of my controller.

Comment: Of course. It should update the value of numOfAbsences.